# Why do some C standard headers begin with 'std' while others don't?

Tags: c, c99, c89, c11

For example, in the new C11 standard there have been added `stdalign.h` and `threads.h`. Why not `stdthreads.h` or `align.h`? Is it to avoid collisions with existing libraries and system headers?

Comment: good question, so +1 for that..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

At various times, there have been various reasons for the names chosen.  `<stdio.h>` was in use as a name long before there was a C standard; the standard simply standardized existing practice.  The `<stddef.h>` header was an invention of the original (C89) committee; its name was chosen because it wasn't in use.  Similarly with `<stdlib.h>`.  The name `<inttypes.h>` was existing practice, but the committee needed `<stdint.h>` to serve free-standing implementations.  The name `<stdarg.h>` was chosen to parallel the non-prototype equivalent `<varargs.h>`.  The name `<stdbool.h>` was not in use; likewise, I guess, `<stdatomic.h>`, `<stdalign.h>`, `<stdnoreturn.h>`.  The `std` prefix is largely reserved for the standard (but I use a header `"stderr.h"`, knowing I could be treading on thin ice).  As to why `<uchar.h>` and `<threads.h>` did not end up with a `std` prefix, I'd hypothesize some prior art that was substantially unchanged.  AFAIK, the C2011 Rationale has not been completed yet; it may reveal more information when it is available.